# java repeat text different times

Tags: java

I'm new with java :-(
I need to get value jee repeated with n times (jeejee, jeejeejee etc.), now I get

jee6 !
Test with value 6: 6
jee2 !
Test with value 2: 2
jee3 !
Test with value 3: 3
jee6 !
Test with value 6: 6
jee3 !
Test with value 3: 3

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test3{
    public static void main(String[] args){<br/>
        final Random r = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
            int n = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("Test with value " + n + ": " + jeeJee(n));
        }
    }

    public static int jeeJee(int i){
        System.out.println( "jee" + i + " !");
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the expected output

Comment: I need to get answer jee with n times (depending what above code says) and !-mark at the end (I forgot that at the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop inside your print function:

```
public static int jeeJee(int i){

    for(int j = 0; j< i; j++)System.out.print( "jee");
    return i;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function **jeejee()** should print "jee", **i** number of times. So for that you can use for loop:

```
 public static int jeeJee(int i){

     System.out.println(i);
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

     for(int k=0;k<i;k++) {
         sb.append("jee");
     }
     System.out.println(sb);
     return i;
 }
```

Comment: If you are not in the need of thread safety with your ```StringBuffer```, you choose use a ```StringBuilder``` instead. In fact, ```StringBuffer``` is synchronized and will have poor performance compare to ```StringBuilder```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 11+ you can use

```java
"jee".repeat(n) + " !";
```